# Magento - displaying a random testimonial

Tags: magento-1.8

I need to show testimonial randomly on home page

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('turnkeye_testimonial/testimonial')->getCollection();   
foreach($collection as $testimonial)
{
   /My Div
}
```

how can i do that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$collection=Mage::getModel('turnkeye_testimonial/testimonial')->getCollection();
 $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
$collection->setPage(1, $numProducts);
foreach($collection as $testimonial)
{
   /My Div
}
```

Comment: not working https://www.notableaccessories.com/index.php/ check  $collection->getSelect()->limit(1)->order('rand()');

Comment: not working  $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
       $collection->setPage(1, 1); i tried with value or $numProducts as well

Comment: i added $collection->getSelect()->limit(1); and works get done, thanks